# Reply to sender with template

Tags: vba, email, outlook, reply

I'm trying to reply to the sender of a selected email with a shared template.

I have two macros.

1. Will reply to sender and insert their address.
2. Will reply with a template (but doesn't insert the sender's address).

Is it possible to combine the two to reply to the email with a template and the sender's address and subject filled in?

1.

```vb
Public Sub AccountSelection()
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim strAccount As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objMsg, oMail As MailItem
  
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Reply
  
If TypeName(ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)) = "MailItem" Then
    Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
    On Error Resume Next
  
    For Each Recipient In oMail.Recipients
        strRecip = Recipient.Address & ";" & strRecip
    Next Recipient
    
    If InStr(strRecip, "alias@domain1.com") = 1 Then
        strAccount = "alias@domain1.com"
    Else
    End If
      
    For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
        If oAccount.DisplayName = strAccount Then
            objMsg.SendUsingAccount = oAccount
        Else
        End If
    Next
  
    objMsg.Display
  
Else
End If
  
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

2. 

```vb
Sub TacReply()
Dim origEmail As MailItem
Dim replyEmail As MailItem
Set origEmail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("S:\Share\TWGeneral.oft")
replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
replyEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@domain.com"
replyEmail.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Realised this wasn't very clear so I have reworded slightly.

Answer (score 3):

To determine the name(s) to send replies, not necessarily the sender

```
origEmail.Reply.To
```

.

```
Sub TacReply()

Dim origEmail As mailItem
Dim replyEmail As mailItem

Set origEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set replyEmail = CreateItemFromTemplate("S:\Share\TWGeneral.oft")

replyEmail.To = origEmail.Reply.To

replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
replyEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@domain.com"
replyEmail.Recipients.ResolveAll
replyEmail.Display

Set origEmail = Nothing
Set replyEmail = Nothing

End Sub
```