# Reply to email with template pictures in signature not displaying

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I'm working off of the macro below to reply to emails but the pictures in my signature are not displaying correctly.  How can I get the pictures in the signature to display correctly?

The images have a red x with the message - the linked image cannot be displayed.  The file might have been removed, renamed, or deleted. etc.

[Outlook Macro - Reply to sender with template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200239/outlook-macro-reply-to-sender-with-template)

Comment: What's the code you are using?

Comment: That's an issue with your template then. The images need to be embedded in the email itself. If you don't send the images along with the mail and they point onto your computer of course the recepient cannot see them. Therefore they are showed as missing. Fix your template and make sure all images are embeded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The templates doesn't contain embedded images. You need to add a referred in the message body image by adding an embedded image and referring to it in the message body.

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\JoeSchmo\Pictures\image.jpg", olByValue, 0
.HTMLBody = "<BODY><IMG src=""cid:image.jpg"" width=200> </BODY>"
```

You may also want to set the following properties:

```
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"
    Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"
```

See [Determine attechments in mail item](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c4f47790-8e7b-425a-bf7e-f7bc5b725e81/determine-attechments-in-mail-item?forum=outlookdev) for more information.

Comment: first of all thank you:) will this add the pictures as attachments? I just want to see the pictures on my signature as if I was replying to any email and my signature appears at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, it will add a picture as an attachment. The `PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN ` property allows to hide it.